# Migrating multiple MVC Applications from Identity to IdentityServer4 - How to pass User cookie between the Applications on the Server via HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Some background...

We have some .NET Core MVC applications which use Identity and some .NET MVC applications that use OWIN. The User logs in once via Identity and then can access any of the applications (via the browser) they have permissions to as they share a single identity database. The applications also can interact on the server by transferring the authorisation cookie via the CookieContainer into a HttpClient. The Applications contain a mixture of MVC Controllers and API Controllers and most of this interaction between the Applications call either an Api endpoint or just a standard MVC Controller HttpGet/Post. These endpoints will be protected by Role based authorisation and a few other Claims.

This is all done via cookies there is no JWT passed or set up at all.

We have some changes coming up in this area so I was wondering if IdentityServer4 could sort out some of the shortcomings in the current setup i.e.

- Centralise the Login/Logout/Profile/User Maintenance logic and views as currently this is spread across  multiple applications

and for the future

- Increase the security of the applications
- Centralise request tokens and refresh tokens for Apps etc
- Centralise using external authorization Google, Facebook and the like

Ive spent a week or so looking into IdentityServer4 and whether we can retrofit it to our current applications initially and ive managed to

- Set up identity server (using the skoruba Admin stuff)
- Migrate our database to it
- Sign in via a .Net Core Client / authorise with the Roles etc
- Sign in via a .Net OWIN client / authorise with the Roles etc

All was good until I got on to pretty much the last major thing

- "The applications also can interact on the server by transferring the authorisation cookie via the CookieContainer into a HttpClient"

Is the equivalent possible if we used IdentityServer? The documents Ive read seem to suggest we would need to isolate all our API functions in a separate controller in each Application so that we can authorise them via a protected APIResource/Scope - most of the endpoints are HttpGets but there are a few HttpPosts which will need to know the User details to update the data - the only mention of this I can find basically says that you need to pass the UserId on the request.

In a nutshell I was hoping that I may be able to retrofit this quickly to our applications to centralising the Login/Logout/User Maintenance aspect and then start looking at the additional benefits later - I was hoping for a "light touch" to each application until it is bedded in but this is starting to look like a lot of work and redesign

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: *“The applications also can interact on the server by transferring the authorisation cookie via the CookieContainer into a HttpClient”* –  Can you expand on this? What exactly do you mean with that? Is this about server-to-server communication, or do you have external clients that call APIs from your applications?

Comment: So User is running a function in MVCApp1 that need to call a function (behind an endpoint) in MVCApp2 so MVCApp1 creates an instance of HttpClient and copies the auth cookie in the current request into a cookiecontainer which is attached to the httpclient and then invokes the endpoint - so the endpoint will be hit in MVCApp2 with the cookie and can validate the user and their roles against the [Authorise] attributes on the endpoint as normal

Comment: Reusing your user’s credentials for authentication against a different application doesn’t really improve your security. For server-to-server communication, you should take a look at the OAuth client credentials grant type, or using a custom grant for delegation. Check out [the IdentityServer docs for an example](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html#example-simple-delegation-using-an-extension-grant).